# L2TP / IPSec connection is succesfull but there is no internet and can't ping local adresses

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I have Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop. I configured the L2TP vpn from UI and it worked. But suddenly it does not work anymore (I didn't change any configuration). I still can connect to VPN without any issues but there is no internet and no connection to servers that are in the same network. My colleagues that use the same VPN do not facing this problems
I configured the VPN in UI this is my configuration:
[image]

[image]

[image]

How to debug my connection?
I've tried:

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager.service
```

But journal is empty.

I've notices that VPN connection is working only few minutes after reboot. It seems like some service is starting and VPN after that not working.

Comment: I have the same problem on ZorinOS based on Ubuntu 22.04. I've tested all known 22.04 VPN issues found by Google - downgrding xl2tpd (LTO problem), using libreswan and strongswan but no success. Tunelling seems to work fine but no packets are forwarded to remote network. After a few minutes vpn disconnect by itself. What about this output?: journalctl --no-hostname _SYSTEMD_UNIT=NetworkManager.service + SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=pppd

Comment: I've tried this command and this is output:
```Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
-- No entries -- ```
I tried it when vpn is on and off, doesn't matter